# Не получается запустить Masonry - Masonry is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт Masonry на сайте под wordpress,но у меня это никак не получается. Хром упорно выдает "Uncaught ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined".

Подключать пробовал и через function.php (скрипт должен быть встроен в wp)

```
function mason_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('masonry');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mason_script' );
```

Пробовал просто выводить в header

```
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
```

Всегда ошибка.

Подскажите, плиз, в чем может быть дело?

Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/gpt46yac/

Answer (score 1):

1. `<script>` надо добавлять в разметку, а не в скрипт.
2. Похоже, они не собираются отдавать так файл.
3. Там нет `content-type`.

Переложи на свой сервер и используй оттуда. Или на pastbin.

Comment: Со своего сервера тоже вызывал - через инструменты разработчика в хроме все открывается, никаких 404.

Обновил код на примере - https://jsfiddle.net/gpt46yac/6/ Все равно скрипт не срабатывает